# Is there a way to access Session Menu with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: unity, 11.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have read this answer  [Will Unity have a keyboard shortcut for accessing the "Session Menu" that appears on the panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30776/will-unity-have-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-accessing-the-session-menu-that-appears), but it doesn't work.

Pressing F10 and using arrow keys only navigates me through the application's panel menu.  I can find no way to access the Session Menu or other Indicator menus with the keyboard. Is there a keyboard shortcut for accessing the session menu so that I can shutdown and log off without using the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

Super + S opens it in 10.10, it should in 11.04 as well.

Comment: SUPER + S brings up the virtual desktops in Unity.