# How to get the shutdown & restart icon back in dash

Tags: unity, 12.04, shutdown, unity-dash

In Ubuntu 11.10 it was possible to type restart or shutdown in dash, so you could drag that icon in the left panel. Now in the new 12.04 this option has been deleted/removed.
Is there another way to get those icons back?

Comment: I find this: http://www.iloveubuntu.net/how-add-shutdown-restart-suspend-hibernate-ubuntu-1204s-dash-ppa-available

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to create two `.desktop` files in your home folder `~/.local/share/applications` with the 11.10 restart and shutdown equivalent files.

Create a text file named as below in the folder. Repeat this for the second desktop file.

Dash will automatically display `restart` and `shutdown` when you type these into dash.

**step by step**

Open a terminal and copy and paste the following one line at a time

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/indicator-session-restart.desktop
```

Copy and paste the text below for *indicator-session-restart.desktop* starting from `[Desktop Entry]` and ending `X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session`

Save and close.

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/indicator-session-shutdown.desktop
```

Copy and paste the text below for *indicator-session-shutdown.desktop* starting from `[Desktop Entry]` and ending `X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session`

Save and close.

#### indicator-session-restart.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Restart
TryExec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --restart
Icon=system-restart
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session
```

#### indicator-session-shutdown.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shut Down
TryExec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown
Icon=system-shutdown
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session
```

Comment: thanx for the reply, tried this, but cannot get it working...
I probably do something wrong. I'm not an Ubuntu expert, just trying to help somebody with this issue...

Comment: ok - I've added some step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> don't hold it, this brings up `HUD` type `Shut Down` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you may find `restart` on that . That is the easy solution :)

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but i cannot drag the icon back in to the left panel...

Comment: i read about those icons are desktop-files that have been removed in the new ubuntu... If they were there in the 11.10 version, i wonder if i cannot make those files myself?

Answer (score 3):

To save space I combined all three actions into one launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Log Out
TryExec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --logout
Icon=system-shutdown
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session

Actions=Restart;ShutDown;

Name[en_US]=Log Out

[Desktop Action ShutDown]
Name=Shut Down
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Restart]
Name=Restart
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --restart
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the update file for "Trusty Tahr"

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Log Out
Exec=dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager "org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout" uint32:1
Icon=system-shutdown
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=2.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gdm

Actions=Restart;Suspend;ShutDown;

Name[en_US]=Log Out

[Desktop Action Restart]
Name=Restart
Exec=dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot" boolean:true
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Suspend]
Name=Suspend
Exec=dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action ShutDown]
Name=Shut Down
Exec=dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Source: [forum.ubuntu-fr.org](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=16497311#p16497311)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 I had to change the Exec= line for shut down to

```
    Exec=dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true
```

as in [askubuntu.com-What command is executed when shutdown from the graphical menu in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454039/what-command-is-executed-when-shutdown-from-the-graphical-menu-in-14-04)