# What command is executed when shutdown from the graphical menu in 14.04?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, 14.04

I understand that clicking "shut down" from the menu that comes up on clicking the cogwheel triggers the following command to be executed:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown
```

However, when I execute this command on a terminal, I get the following error:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
```

Is it because 14.04 uses some other service for shutting down, or am I doing something wrong?

---

Note: This question is in follow-up of:

- [Why do we need to be root in terminal for shutdown and restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361988/why-do-we-need-to-be-root-in-terminal-for-shutdown-and-restart)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line The answer here should be moved to the other question as it is well-formatted and correct...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`systemd-logind` manages user sessions in 14.04 (replacing consolekit and upower with login1), the commands to use are now:

**PowerOff**:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true
```

**Reboot**:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot" boolean:true
```

**Suspend**:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true
```

**Hibernate**:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Hibernate" boolean:true
```

Source: [forum.ubuntu-fr.org](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=16497311#p16497311)

Comment: Works exactly as intended, but would be great if you could mention the source of the solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a source