# Enable shutdown from another computer on LAN without entering sudo password

Tags: server, ssh, password, sudo, shutdown

I'm trying to execute this script from my laptop to shutdown the server without having to enter the sudo password. (Both are running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS)

```
ssh -t lachlan@192.168.0.xxx sudo shutdown -h now


lachlan@lachlan-MacBookAir:~/.scripts$ ./optiplex_990_shutdown.sh
[sudo] password for lachlan: 
Connection to 192.168.0.xxx closed.
```

As you can see it still asks for password. The following lines are included in the sudoers file edited using `sudo visudo`.

```
Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN_CMDS = /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot
lachlan lachlan-MacBookAir= NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN_CMDS
```

The output from `sudo -l` is

```
User lachlan may run the following commands on ubuntu:
(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot
(ALL : ALL) ALL
```

BTW lachlan is also the username for admin on the server

I've also tried to run the following

```
ssh lachlan@192.168.0.xxx dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

and i get the following in terminal

```
Error org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.NotPrivileged: Not Authorized
```

I would prefer to use the second method `dbus-send` and I have this working for my intel NUC running Kodibuntu but the Ubuntu server must be more secure in some way.  BTW I've set up Key-based authentication for ssh connections so it's not that asking me for the password.

Thanks in advance. Apologies for the bad formatting in this post (first question)

I've compared the contents of
`/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.consolekit.policy`
on both machines, the intel nuc running kodibuntu and the optiplex 990 running ubuntu server and they're both the same.  So it must be that there are multiple user logged in right? No. I tried logging multiple user in to the nuc via ssh from 2 other laptops and checked with `who -a`.  Then I ran the following script
`ssh lachlan@192.168.0.xxx dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop`
No problem, all works. I logged the same 2 computers in to the ubuntu server and ran the same script and I get
`Error org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.NotPrivileged: Not Authorized`

Ok. From terminal on each machine just to eliminate any stupid mistakes I might be making I entered the command
`dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop`
and same result. So on kodibuntu you don't have to be admin and on ubuntu server you do.  How do you change that & should I?

Comment: In case you do run dbus services try with login manager rather than consolekit: http://askubuntu.com/a/454077/3940

Comment: Thanks Takkat. I tried the following from the link.
`ssh -t lachlan@192.168.0.xxx dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true`

In terminal I get a similar permissions problem
`lachlan@lachlan-MacBookAir:~/.scripts$ ./optiplex_990_shutdown.sh Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Operation not permitted
Connection to 192.168.0.xxx closed.`
When I ssh in and try sudo any of these methods they all work, it just doesn't work remotely yet without sudo and password for shutting down the server