# Is there a command to open the shutdown GUI?

Tags: shutdown, gui

I know I can shutdown from commandline - without a password: [What command is executed when shutdown from the graphical menu in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454039/what-command-is-executed-when-shutdown-from-the-graphical-menu-in-14-04) but I can't see how to open the shutdown GUI. Is this possible?

Comment: The accepted answer is way out of date, but the last answer is correct, AFAIK.

Comment: @muru this is not working for ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Tim what is your Version?

Comment: @Tim Ok good, For me it doesn't work

Comment: @Maythux worked fine for me on 14.04 too.

Comment: @muru, It's something crazy!! I  have two machines 14.04 one virtual and other physical  and none of them works! while works for 12.04 smoothly!! I have to investigate to know the problem. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 3):

- Shutdown:

  ```
  /usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown
  ```
- Reboot

  ```
  /usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --restart
  ```
- Logout

  ```
  /usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --logout
  ```

---

You can also use another dialog:

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off
```

---