# Hot Corners Musical Sequence Command Script

Tags: command-line, sound, bash, scripts

I am writing a script which uses **hot corners to play specific musical notes when hovering in corners, and depending on the musical sequence to execute a specific command.**

The script is called with parameter -d from bottom left, -e from b-right, -g from top-left, -b from top-right, appends the sequence in a file (~/bin/for_hot) and compares the sequence with my associative array. Plays a succesful musical B'' when the sequence is recognized.

**2 issues:**

**Sometimes the commands won't execute, even though the succesful sound plays;**

**I don't manage to poweroff. [SOLVED]**

I think I am not monitoring the processes adequately afterwards (kill, background), and also the file (~/bin/for_hot) I am appending may not be written to in time.

Here is the script, please note I am a noob in linux so don't hate my code, my question, me too much:

```
#!/bin/bash

#switch###############################
case "$1" in
-d) play -q -n synth 3 pluck 293.665 &
sleep 0.5
echo -n "d" >> ~/bin/for_hot;
;;
-e) play -q -n synth 3 pluck 311.127 &
sleep 0.5
echo -n "e" >> ~/bin/for_hot;
;;
-g) play -q -n synth 3 pluck 391.995 &
sleep 0.5
echo -n "g" >> ~/bin/for_hot;
;;
-b) play -q -n synth 3 pluck 466.164 &
sleep 0.5
echo -n "b" >> ~/bin/for_hot;
;;
esac
######################################

#midi mappings########################
declare -A commands
commands=( 
["egbd"]="firefox -n" 
["ebgb"]="idea" 
["ebb"]="notify-send "$instr "" 
["egdgb"]="echo pass | sudo -S poweroff"
["ee"]="nemo /home/mintbwoy");
######################################


s=$(<~/bin/for_hot);

for pattern in "${!commands[@]}";
do
echo "$pattern - ${commands["$pattern"]}";

if [[ "$s" == *"$pattern"* ]]
then
echo -n "" > ~/bin/for_hot;
play -q -n synth 3 pluck 932.328 &
var=$(${commands["$s"]});
$var;
notify-send "[$pattern] = ${commands["$pattern"]} "$var"";
fi

done
######################################
```

Comment: Use dbus to avoid using `sudo` with shutdown : http://askubuntu.com/a/454077/295286

Comment: @Serg There was one more question beside that.

Comment: Ah, well. Technically it's against the rules - one question per post. Try adding echo before $var , see what it says, if the commands are executed properly. Also , scripts are sequential, so if you have one command running, the script will wait for it to exit. Id use `eval "$var" "&" `  , but that's not a 100% correct syntax. I'm on mobile and don't remember it off the top of my head

Comment: @Serg apparently eval does the job really well, not sure why but my script is now even more responsive. Thank you

Comment: Ok， i guess i can post an answer now

Comment: @Serg Absolutely m8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used eval to execute the command and:

**var=$(${commands["$s"]})** got changed to

**var=$(${commands["$pattern"]})** because I was refering the file content instead of the actual pattern.